# Python: try-catch-else without handling the exception. Possible?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I am new to python and is wondering if I can make a try-catch-else statement without handling the exception?

Like:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
else:
    print("Message: ", line) // complains about that else is not intended
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following sample code shows you how to catch and ignore an exception, using pass.

```
try:
    do_something()
except RuntimeError:
    pass # does nothing
else:
    print("Message: ", line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will mark this answer as corrected in a few minutes (it is not possible for some minutes)

Comment: The question was to *not* handle the exception - better to use `raise` than `pass`.

Answer (score 18):

While I agree that Jochen Ritzel's is a good answer, I think there may be a small oversight in it. By `pass`ing, the exception /is/ being handled, only nothing is done. So really, the exception is ignored.

If you really don't want to handle the exception, then the exception should be `raise`d. The following code makes that change to Jochen's code.

```
try:
    do_something()
except RuntimeError:
    raise #raises the exact error that would have otherwise been raised.
else:
    print("Message: ", line)
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly identical to `do_something(); print("Message: ", line)`?

Comment: @KirkStrauser yes, but `explicit is better than implicit`.  Any user will see that an except is expected, and then raised to the caller, without having to look up whether `do_something` raises any exceptions.

Comment: @Darthfett I think that's going overboard. If you think that an exception is likely to crop up, you should handle it properly (even if that's just printing a user-friendly message) otherwise, just leave it out.

Comment: If it was me, `do_something()` wouldn't `raise`. I'd call `do_something` and then `raise` explicitly

Comment: Are you saying that if do_something() encounters an error internal to that function, you'd rather attempt to detect that outside of the function and then raise an exception, on its behalf, outside of the function call?  That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: I want to agree with @Lattyware now. I do think that this is going a little overboard. `do_something()` should handle exceptions internally and potentially raise others, should the need arise (these should be well documented, however)

Comment: Just to note: This format is indeed useful if you ever want to handle else AND finally, but allow exceptions to propagate unobstructed. (e.g. returning from function on `else`, closing acquired connections on `finally`, and letting the rest of your script handle an `except` as normal)